# how to programatically determine if the form was instantiated or simply opened

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've a form MyForm thatmay be launched in two ways:

```
    docmd.openform "MyForm"
```

or

```
    dim FF as form
    set FF = new Form_MyForm
    FF.Visible = True
```

The issue is : I need to launch SeekCustomer() ONLY in case the form was launched by docmd.openform...

How can I do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this for the first case:

```
Dim OpenArgs As Variant
OpenArgs = "*"
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , , , , , OpenArgs
```

Then, when you open the form, check for:

```
If Not IsNull Me.OpenArgs) Then
    SeekCustomer()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use this solution because some existing modules open this form and I can't modify them for some reasons I'm unable to explain in english. The only way for me is to improve MyForm in a transparent way for existing code. That was the goal of my previous question you answered .

Comment: Well, if you can't change anything you are, of course, hosed.

Comment: I won't surrender ;-) Thanks